# I have a lot of error of Connection timed out after 50ms

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I have a dynamoDB and a nodejs service the use aws-sdk v3 and when I see the error in the see "Connection timed out after 50ms"

```
const requestHandler = new NodeHttpHandler({
      connectionTimeout: 50,
      socketTimeout: 50,
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: 50,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
      }),
      httpAgent: new http.Agent({
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: 50,
      }),
    });

    const [endpoint] = this.endpoints;
    let  service = new DynamoDB({
        region: this.region,
        endpoint,
        requestHandler,
        maxAttempts: 3,
      });
```

what could be the problem everyone said to reduce the number of attempts to 30 and reduce the timeout to 50ms and I did this and still, I don't understand why This happend

Answer (score 0):

A timeout of 50ms is quite aggressive, perhaps for a table where you are making a lot of requests which are singleton requests such as GetItem or PutItem it would be ok. But for a table where requests are infrequent where you need to establish a connection or range requests such as Query or Scan then 50ms is too aggressive and this is why you're getting time outs.

While this blog focusses on Java, the timeouts remain relevant for Node also:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/tuning-aws-java-sdk-http-request-settings-for-latency-aware-amazon-dynamodb-applications/